Apex Batch QueryLocator : SOQL statements cannot query aggregate relationships more than 1 level away from the root entity object
I am writing a Batch Apex job that will process the Account records. In my SOQL query, I also want to query the child records of the Account SObject. The child records are for the immediate child Contact object and the child of Contact object. So, I am traversing multiple children Account -> Contacts -> Contact_Consents__r.
Before summer'24 release this was not possible with a single SOQL query but now with summer'24 release this should be possible.
When I try to use this feature with the getQueryLocator class I get the below error. I have no issue is querying data with a normal SOQL query.

SOQL statements cannot query aggregate relationships more than 1 level away from the root entity object

This works in anonymous apex
List<Account> accts = [Select Id, (Select id, (Select id from Contact_Consents__r) from Contacts) from Account];
This doesn't work in anonymous apex
Database.getQueryLocator([Select Id, (Select id, (Select id from Contact_Consents__r) from Contacts) from Account limit 1]);
Is this a known limitation of this feature?

Even if this were supported, this is a bad idea. Even using just plain one-level subquery causes significant performance penalties in batchable classes in the start method. You can, and should, query for related records in the execute method, like this:
Account[] accounts = [
  Select Id, 
    (Select id, 
       (Select id from Contact_Consents__r) 
     from Contacts) 
  from Account WHERE Id IN :scope];

Not only will this significantly reduce the start method's execution time, it will also ensure that your your batch class isn't working on stale data.

Thanks for the reply.
In my case, I am working on some historical data migration. The number of records to be processed is around 200k as my existing query already filters irrelevant records. So, this is why I hope to utilize the start method to have a single query that returns all the records, instead of querying the child records as part of each execute method execution.

@RanRag Again, don't. It will have a very strong performance penalty compared to querying the records when you need them.

Thank you for sharing this insight. I am curious is this performance penalty documented somewhere or more based on your experience?

@RanRag I don't know if it's officially documented, but I have heard from reliable sources that query locators with subqueries run slower than those without. I don't have an org with enough data to confirm this, though. Regardless, remember that records can be modified in between the initial query and the execute method, which means you can run into stale data. It's just generally a bad idea to query all the fields you want upfront.

Thank you! I have updated the logic at my end. But still, the original question remains, is it a bug or an intended behaviour?
